# Copy all rows between two strings that aren´t at the start of the row-python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I´m new at this world and I need to do this with this kind of file:

......|4751|......

.

.


.


.

.
.
99999|

I wanna to search for this string "|4751|" and copy all rows and the row with the string "|4751|" until the line that contains 99999|

The text has multiples "|4751|" and 99999| and I wanna copy all the rows between all of them

Is this possible with python? I´ve found some posts here, but the problem is that I can´t adapt the script, because my string |4751| is in the middle of the row, and not at the start of it.

Comment: Is the text in a file? well since you said you are new, if the text in a file then this specific kind of work is best done using `perl` and not `python`. I am in no way saying python will not do it but rather claiming this is quick and easy to do in perl.

Comment: It is a .txt file.

Comment: well in that case doing `perl -ne "print if /\\|4751\\|/../.*99999/" dat.txt > dat1.txt`will solve your problem. Of course you do this on the command line where `dat.txt` exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can build a custom iterator (and context manager) that retrieves the desired rows from the input file

```
class Collector:
    def __init__(self, filename, start_marker, stop_marker):
        self.toggle_collect = False
        self.f = open(filename)
        self.m1 = start_marker
        self.m2 = stop_marker

    def __enter__ (self):
        return self

    def __exit__ (self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.f.close()

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        while True:
            r = next(self.f)
            if self.m1 in r:  # found the start-collecting marker
                self.toggle_collect = True
            elif self.m2 in r:  # found the stop-collecting marker
                self.toggle_collect = False
                continue
            if self.toggle_collect:  # we are collecting
                return r.rstrip()  # collect row


with Collector('file_rows.txt', '4751', '99999') as c:
    for r in c:
        print(r)
```

which, with an input file of

```
foobar0
foo|4751|bar1
foobar2
foo99999|bar3
foobar4
foobar5
foo|4751|bar6
foo99999|bar7
foobar8
```

produces

```
foo|4751|bar1

foobar2

foo|4751|bar6
```

Note: as you can see in the output, the rows are spaced with a blank line. It's because they include the Carriage Return.

If it's not needed, we can strip it off

```
            if self.toggle_collect:  # we are collecting
                return r.rstrip()  # provide row
```

In case we wanted the rows in a list, simply create one from the iterator

```
with Collector('file_rows.txt', '4751', '99999') as c:
    results = list(c)
```

Comment: I´m very new to computer. I can see the results at the screen, because of print command, but how can I save the lines I wanna at a .txt file? Thanks for the answer

Comment: EDIT2: I managed to save the with  "write("%s\n" % r)" as a list. Thanks a lot for the help =)

Comment: Just one last question. Is it possible to this script with multiples txt at once?

Comment: Of course,  but the subject of the question is increasing   and becoming a consultation. My rate is... :)

Comment: Write me in private and describe the inputs/outputs you desire, so I can point you to the right solution

Comment: Thanks! I wrote an e-mail for you at your gmail.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.findall` with `re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL` flags, and a lookahead. Be sure to escape the `|` characters, which have a special meaning in regular expressions:

```
import re

haystack = """foobar0
foo|4751|bar1
foobar2
foo99999|bar3
foobar4
foobar5
foo|4751|bar6
foo99999|bar7
foobar8"""

needle = "^[^\n]*\|4751\|.*?(?=99999\|)"
result = re.findall(needle, haystack, re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)

print (result)
```

which results in:

> ```
> ['foo|4751|bar1\nfoobar2\nfoo', 'foo|4751|bar6\nfoo']
> ```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this later. Let´s say I don´t wanna the 99999| to be at my final txt, just that the search stops there and go next to |4751| and copy until the next 99999|, but without copying the 99999| itself to the final file. What should I do at your code? Thanks for your help

Comment: @eduardomb I edited the answer to account for that. Don't forget to [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/405359) if it helped you.